# A tricky GNU make problem

Tags: sqlite, dependencies, makefile, gnu-make

Here's some pseudocode for what I want my makefile to do:

```
if (A doesn't exist) or (B is newer than A):
    rm -rf A
    create an empty A
parallel_for X in (a large set of files):
    if (X is newer than A):
        update A using the contents of X
```

In the above pseudocode, `A` is an SQLite database, `B` is a C header file, and each of the files in the "large set of files" is a C source file.

Basically, if I only modify one of the C source files, I just want the database to be quickly updated rather than rebuilding the entire database from scratch.

Is this type of problem solvable directly in GNU make, or am I going to have to resort to using a script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
A:: B
        -rm -f $@
        create_A $@

A:: $(all_X)
        update_A_from_Xes $@ $?
```

`$?` expands to the subset of `$(all_X)` that are newer than A (see the "[Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) section of the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/) for more details).  Therefore, `update_A_from_Xes` must update its first argument with respect to *all* of the subsequent arguments; it will only be invoked once.

The [double colons](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html) tell Make that the commands to run to update A are different when it's out of date with respect to B than when it's out of date with respect to the Xes.  I am not sure whether both sets of commands will get run in the case that it is out of date with respect to both; if they do both get run, the `A:: B` rules will get run first.

Comment: Thanks Zack! I just learned not one, but *two* new things about GNU make! :D